# Why is data not being sent to another component using service?

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a login component that gets response from database. The response contains many fields and using a service, data goes from one component to another component using getter and setter. But the data is not going between the component even though another component gets the data from that same service's getter.

shared.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  setData(data: any) {
    this.dataSubject.next(data);
  }

  getData() {
    return this.dataSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

login.component.ts :

```
this.loginService.validateEmployee(formData)
      .subscribe(
        (response:any) => {
          if(response!==null)
          {
            this.sharedService.setData(response);
            this.router.navigate(['/employee']);
          }
        });
```

myorders.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myorders',
  templateUrl: './myorders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myorders.component.css']
})
export class MyordersComponent implements OnInit {
  receivedData:any;
  employeeId:number;

  constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.receivedData = data;
      this.employeeId=this.receivedData.employeeId;
    });
  }
}
```

This is giving employeeId as null. even recievedData is null. But, there is another component, product.component.ts that does this same code and gets the employeeId. why ?

I have tried using different method to store employeeId alone in the same service file but its also not working. Also, I have tried to pass employeeId as parameter from login.component.ts Its also giving null. The Login Component is setting values to shared.service at the initialization and after that, we go to MyOrders Component init to get data. Then, we are not getting the values

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code using my eyes.  What do you say it is getting `null`?  Was that using a debugger or something else?

Comment: In myorders.component.ts, on console.log(receivedData) the value is null

Comment: Can you check if `SharedService` is listed in the `providers` array in another module or component? If so, you might be getting separate instances of the service.

Comment: Because you've chosen to use a `BehaviorSubject` you will always get null to begin with.  Do you get `null` twice after you know the `next` has been called?

Comment: I have checked and SharedService is listed in the providers only in the module.ts file of the project and not in any other component

Comment: But i am getting the values in admin.component and product.component.

Comment: **NOT** include in providers, you yet defined your service as `providedIn:root`, each time you include in a providers array of a module, you get a new instance of the service

Comment: But i have removed it from providers. Then also , data is not getting

Comment: I made a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4jjng9?file=src%2Fmain.ts). It's standalone, but it's equal. see that in any place are a "providers" array. Ones you navigate to login, navigate to One show the data sended. BTW Check if you're calling to `sharedService.setData()` in another place